# Sequence contains no elements being thrown only from AutoFixture

Tags: c#, .net, exception, testing, autofixture

I use AutoFixture with my BDD tests.

I'm trying to write a fixture for a `User` class which in turn uses `CentralConfiguration` class. `CentralConfiguration` constructor looks like this:

```
public CentralConfiguration(
    IConfigurationRepository configurationRepository,
    ILogger logger)
{
   _logger = logger;
   _configuration = configurationRepository.Single();
   LogPropertyValues();
}
```

The second line in the constructor, although working fine when used by a user, throws "Sequence contains no elements" exception *every time* I try to build a fixture for tests. I even tried building a `Configuration` object manually and using

```
configuration.Single().Returns(myCustomObject)
```

but nothing changed (actually this line started throwing the same exception).

What am I doing wrong, and how can I circumvent this issue?

Comment: Are you using an auto-mocking Glue Library as well? (e.g. AutoFixture.AutoMoq)

Comment: If `CentralConfiguration` only depends on a single `Whatchamacallit`, then why don't you inject _that_ instead? [Injection Constructors should be simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple).

Answer (score 0):

Change `CentralConfiguration` to:

```
public CentralConfiguration(
    IConfiguration configuration,
    ILogger logger)
{
   _logger = logger;
   _configuration = configuration;
   LogPropertyValues();
}
```

Also consider removing the call to `LogPropertyValues` from the constructor. [Injection Constructors should be simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple).